# How to fix a bad upgrade of pip on python3

Tags: python, pip

Before someone slaps my hand, I had installed venv/virtualenv to setup virtual environments but I had other issues so someone suggested I upgrade my pip3 version to the current version (22.0.4 right now)

I somehow messed up both pip and pip3 so hopefully someone can help me.

I tried to upgrade my version of pip on my Ubuntu 16.04 box by running

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip
```

I also tried running

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip3
```

After upgrading, I kept getting errors when trying to run pip3 so I removed it, planning to install with the get-pip.py script.

However, now when I try to install pip3 using

```
sudo python3 /tmp/get-pip.py
```

I keep getting an AttributeError:

```
$ sudo python3 /tmp/get-pip.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/get-pip.py", line 27077, in <module>
    main()
  File "/tmp/get-pip.py", line 135, in main
    bootstrap(tmpdir=tmpdir)
  File "/tmp/get-pip.py", line 111, in bootstrap
    monkeypatch_for_cert(tmpdir)
  File "/tmp/get-pip.py", line 92, in monkeypatch_for_cert
    from pip._internal.commands.install import InstallCommand
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 656, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 626, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "/tmp/tmpu1lmh2fr/pip.zip/pip/_internal/commands/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
...
...
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 656, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 626, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "/tmp/tmpu1lmh2fr/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/pyparsing.py", line 5677, in <module>
  File "/tmp/tmpu1lmh2fr/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/pyparsing.py", line 1488, in setResultsName
  File "/tmp/tmpu1lmh2fr/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/pyparsing.py", line 1491, in _setResultsName
  File "/tmp/tmpu1lmh2fr/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/pyparsing.py", line 1445, in copy
AttributeError: module 'copy' has no attribute 'copy'
```

Can someone point me to instructions on how to re-install pip/pip3 or how to get around this AttributeError?  Hopefully the solution will also keep my old modules that I had downloaded from before too.  Thanks

Comment: Check if there is `/tmp/copy.py` file. Try these commands: `sudo python3 -c "import copy; print(copy.copy)"` and `sudo python3 -c "import copy; print(copy.__file__)"`

Comment: @phd, thx for your help.  So there was a dir called "copy" in the /tmp dir.  Not sure why that caused problems but once I moved the dir, the initial problem went away.  I might need to create another question for this new problem I'm running into.  If you make this comment into an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if there is a file `/tmp/copy.py` or directory+file `/tmp/copy/__init__.py`. Try these commands: `sudo python3 -c "import copy; print(copy.copy)"` and `sudo python3 -c "import copy; print(copy.__file__)"`

If any of those exists it will be imported instead of [standard module `copy`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html) because Python prepends the directory of a script (the script is `/tmp/get-pip.py`, the directory `/tmp/`) at the beginning of `sys.path` so it's where Python starts to find modules/packages.